# Moving Drupal 7 Site from Host to Host

Tags: drupal-7

I have created a new Drupal 7 site at an address "http://www.mycms.com/customer".  I am trying to move it to the production server at "http://www.customer.com".  I backed up the database adn restored it on the "www.customer.com" MySQL server.  I copied all the files from the "http://www.mycms.com/customer" folders.  I cleared the cache_* tables in the database.

When I go to "http://www.customer.com", the home page is successfully displayed, but when I click any link on the home page, I get 1 "404 Not found" error.  If I try to go to a page directly, e.g., "http://www.customer.com/node/15", the same error is displayed.

Additional info -

1. The .htaccess file was copied from the appropriate subdirectory.
2. There are no redirects in the .htaccess file
3. When I attempt to login, I get the same error, so I cannot check any settings within the drupal database itself, except via phpAdmin.

Anybody have any ideas what to check next.

Comment: I went back to the database associated with "http://www.mycms.com/customer".  I turned off "CleanURL's".  I then backed up the database and restored it at the new URL "http://www.customer.com".  All the pages are now accessible.

The new question is how do I turn back on the "CleanURL's".  With the new database, the "CleanURL's" test fails; therefore, I cannot turn them back on.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, it sounds like you are moving the site to a different server (not just a different URL)?

If moving to a different server, my initial thought is that if the .htaccess file is the same and clean url's do not work on the new server then it's the Apache configuration that needs tweaked.  Do you have other sites working on this new server?

```
AllowOverride All
```

needs to be set in your httpd.conf for one.

Answer (score 1):

Alexey is right. Solved my problem.
In httpd.conf, find and enable mod_rewrite.

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the current .htaccess file, and upload the standard .htaccess file that comes shipped with drupal.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that mod_rewrite is disabled. On your customer server create a file, i.e. info.php  with contents:

```
<?phpinfo();
```

Then call it from your browser. Search for "Loaded modules" text. It must contain "mod_rewrite" (see image below).

You need this apache module enabled if you want clean urs to work.

[image: loaded modules image]